# Can't reach kubernetes pods using a service via kubectl proxy

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I have a deamonset which defines

```
ports:
- containerPort: 24231
```

in spec.

After deploying a set I can curl `/metrics` endpoint on localhost(in container) and can curl the endpoint of one container from another container of the same set.

Then I define a service like this:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: fluentd
  labels:
    app: fluentd
spec:
  ports:
    - name: prometheus
      port: 80
      targetPort: 24231
  selector:
    app: fluentd
```

I expect that this will allow me to:
`kubectl proxy --port=8001`

And after following the link:
`http://127.0.0.1:8001/api/v1/namespaces/default/services/fluentd:prometheus/proxy/metrics`

What I see is this:

```
Error: 'dial tcp 10.136.4.30:24231: i/o timeout'
Trying to reach: 'http://10.136.4.30:24231/metrics'
```

But `http://127.0.0.1:8001/api/v1/namespaces/default/services/fluentd` returns me service information as expected which includes:

```
"spec": {
    "ports": [
      {
        "name": "prometheus",
        "protocol": "TCP",
        "port": 80,
        "targetPort": 24231
```

What am I doing wrong. This service has worked a week ago, but stopped working after redeployment.

Comment: Maybe check if checkbox Deploy Dashboard in GCP console is selected? GCP is [moving away from the dashboards](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/dashboards) but I believe you can still use it

Comment: @KurtisStreutker thanks, I do know they are moving away from them. However, proxy is not only used for that. it's for general purpose api interactions. One example of such interaction may be scraping and auto discovering service properties. Which is what I need it for. Not for the dashboard.

Comment: @user3081519 can you list your endpoints `kubectl  get ep -owide`
`

Answer (score 1):

This was a GKE issue that I had to resolve with their support.

Answer (score 0):

There are few things you should check:

1. Endpoints - if you can reach them through your service
2. Check selectors and labels - if they are correct
3. Use `kubectl port-forward` instead of proxy - if the points above did not help. More about it [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#port-forward).

I have listed my suggestion from the most probable one to the least.
Please let me know if that helped.